# Regex to replace specific control characters except a few special cases C#?

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following requirement:

i have a string str which has control characters...i want to replace these control characters with some specific values. So i am using the following Regex as:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{C}+","\r\n");
```

The above replaces ALL control characters with \r\n.

However, I want to do the same thing above but exclude the following control characters :

```
SPACE , `\u000D`, `\u000A`
```

How can i modify the RegEx above to accomplish this?
Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [character class subtraction](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\p{C}-[ \u000D\u000A]]+","\r\n");
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `[\p{C}-[ \u000D\u000A]]+` pattern matches 1 or more chars from the `\p{C}` Unicode category *except* a space, `\u000D` and `\u000A`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: `[^\P{C}\r\n]+`

Negative class `[^`
Negative property `\P{C}`  (negative class + negative property = `\p{C}`)
Carriage return `\r`
Line feed `\n`

Result: All control codes excluding CRLF.

*(btw: SPACE is not matched by `\p{C}`)*